# Free Shipping option with multiple "Method Name"

Tags: magento-1, free-shipping

I have a few rules for "Free Shipping", however, the output for the "Method Name" is a general label that doesn't make sense for one of my free shipping options.

Example:

Free Shipping Rule 1: Display "Shipping Courier 1"

Free Shipping Rule 2: Display "Software Virtual License"

Is there a way to change the Free Shipping "Method Name" based on a rule? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

---

EDIT: Since I cannot change these products to a virtual product, is it possible to create an observer on the cart and checkout page that would treat these products with a specific attribute as a virtual product?

How would I create a basic observer to by-pass the shipping?

Comment: Updated my answer according to your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set up the free shipping rules with table rates where you can define different names.

But "Software Virtual License" looks like a special case. Software licenses should be virtual products and if you have only virtual products in the cart, the shipping step is skipped completely.

---

## Answer to updated question:

> Since I cannot change these products to a virtual product, is it possible to create an observer on the cart and checkout page that would treat these products with a specific attribute as a virtual product?
>
> How would I create a basic observer to by-pass the shipping?

The method that's used to determine if a quote is virtual, i.e. the shipping step is skipped, is [`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::isVirtual()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L1693-L1709).

You see that the only way to influence the result without rewriting this method would be to make the products `getIsVirtual()` method return true:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getIsVirtual())
```

Unfortunately [this method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1668-L1671) uses the product type singleton instance:

```
return $this->getTypeInstance(true)->isVirtual($this);
```

And for simple products, the [`isVirtual()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php#L283-L286) method simply returns false:

```
public function isVirtual($product = null)
{
    return false;
}
```

So, there is no way to modify the behavior with an observer, but you have the choice which model to rewrite:

- `sales/quote`
- `catalog/product`
- `catalog/product_type_simple`

This is something like a choice between pest, cholera and hemorrhoids. Between those, I'd always choose the latter but it's still not nice.

Comment: I agree they should be virtual products, but since they are already simple products I cannot change them so this is the work around. Table rates wont work either because all my shipping calculations are done through my suppliers. A free shipping rule would allow me to create the option that would bypass my supplier since they dont give a response to virtual products on shipping - which in turn does not allow a visitor to checkout for these products.

Comment: @SR_Magento couldn't you change the product type in the DB > "catalog_product_entity" from simple to virtual?

Comment: @dawhoo it would work but we are talking a couple of thousand products and wouldnt address the new ones that are brought in regularly.